# Preventing A HREF redirect but still completing action?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page using Jquery Mobile list view. I'm trying to find a way to keep the listview look, but have a button that executes a command, without redirecting like normal  do.

Here is how the Ahrefs are generated.

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if ($row['photoLink'] == NULL)
        {
            $row['photoLink'] = "endofgroup";
            $row['lastName'] = "End Of Group " ;
            $ID = "&ID=".$row['ID'];
        }
        if ($row[leftGym] == "1") { $flash = "style='color:#B22222;font-size:140%'";} else {$flash ="";}
            $row['firstName'] = strtoupper($row['firstName']);
        $row['lastName'] = strtoupper($row['lastName']);
            echo "<li><a href='WPSelect.php?sid=${row['sID']}' $flash  style='font-size:140%;' width='25px' data-ajax='false'>&nbsp;  &nbsp;  {$row["lastName"]}, {$row["firstName"]}</a><div class='split-custom-wrapper'>
            <a href='WDData.php?sID={$row['sID']}&lane=1{$ID}'  data-role='button' class='split-custom-button' data-icon='delete' data-rel='dialog' data-theme='c'  data-ajax='false' data-iconpos='notext'></a>           
        </div></li>";
    }
    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

and here is the code I tried

```
<script>
$(function() {
//Attache the click event and perform this function
  $("a").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //preven the page from navigating, the default behaviour for a link
    $.ajax({
      url: this.href, //perform a ajax request witht the link
      /* type: POST, */
      beforeSend: function() {
        $("#status").text('Working..')
      }
    }).done(function(data) {
      console.log(data); //do something with the data if any
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log("ERROR"); //report in console for errors
      console.info(jqXHR);
      console.info(textStatus);
      console.info(errorThrown);
    }).always(function() {
      $("#status").text('completed..')
      console.info("completed"); //do this step everytime irrespective of result
    });
  })
})
</script>
```

Can anyone see what I could be doing wrong? Or is my idea even possible? Is there a better way to go about this? All I want is the user to be able to click the link, stay on the same page, but process the script on the referenced page.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return false;` at the end of your click function. If that doesn't do it, your database response is returning something that redirects.

Comment: I found a header: location php in the middle. would that cause it?

Comment: That's your problem then

Comment: That fixed it, thank you very much. I didn't realize that it would still obey header redirects when using prevent default..but it makes sense - The prevent default only affects the A tag I just realized.